# Faker.js Generating random paths doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, karma-jasmine, angularjs-e2e

I am using ***faker.js*** 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker
to *generate random data*. It works fine although when I try to create a ***path*** like this

```
faker.system.directoryPath() + '/' + faker.system.filePath()
```

I have always got **undefined** in both, so it seems that it exists but doesn't return anything.

Did anyone use one of these methods before?

Thanks in advance, any help would be really appreciated.

Bye

Answer (score 2):

Those functionalities are not implemented - take a look into https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/master/lib/system.js#L132 and https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/master/lib/system.js#L141

```
  /**
   * not yet implemented
   *
   * @method faker.system.filePath
   */
  this.filePath = function () {
    // TODO
  };
```

Some proof of concept how it can be implemented:

```
var faker = require('faker');
var path = require('path');

faker.directoryPath = function() {
  return path.format({base: faker.fake("{{random.words}}").replace(/ /g, path.sep).toLowerCase()})
}

console.log(faker.directoryPath() + path.sep + faker.system.fileName()) // e.g. avon\re-engineered\strategist_gorgeous_wooden_fish_cambridgeshire.sm
```